# Flutter : Add identifier (key) for dynmically created ui elements

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I need to assign an identifier(key) for all the UI elements in my flutter application for appium automation. So far i have been doing it using  `key: Key('someKey'),` for the static elements like buttons etc. But not sure how to generate key for dynamically created UI elements like for the the below list items. I need to assign key value for each list items.

```
 ListView.builder(
  itemCount: items.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  final item = items[index];
  return ListTile(
    title: item.buildTitle(context),
    subtitle: item.buildSubtitle(context),
  );
 },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UniqueKey()` UniqueKey creates a unique key for every dynamically created widget. for more reference [UniqueKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/UniqueKey-class.html)